Importing OpenCV in Android Studio
I want to import OpenCV in android studio but unable to do it. I looked on internet but all the procedure given make me stuck at one place. Whenever i try to import module from source it says "Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project. Any suggestions?
whenever i remove "\java" from the address i get proceed option but that's not how it should be done and i get error later on also.

Importing OpenCV as a project instead of a module solved this problem for me.
e.g
File->New->Import Project
instead of
File->New->Import Module
